# Como usar randômico no C++?

Tags: c++

Gostaria de um exemplo da utilização do randômico no C++, pois preciso utiliza-lo mas não sei como funciona.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O código abaixo gera 10 números aleatórios de 0 até 10; se você que números aleatórios com um intervalo maior, só mudar a linha `item = rand() % 100;` (agora ele vai gerar 10 elementos com o intervalo de 0 à 100.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  int i;
  int item;
  for ( i = 1; i <= 10; i++ ) { 
    item = rand() % 10;
    printf( "%3d ", item );
  }
}
```

Comment: não era para gerar números aleatório, toda fez sai o mesmo numero.

Comment: Rodolfo, você deve alimentar com um valor de seed para gerar os números aleatórios. Pesquise sobre srand.

Answer (score 7):

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using namespace std;

    random_device rng; // Gerador de números randômicos próprio para gerar seeds.
    mt19937 prng(rng()); // Gerador pseudo-randômico Mersenne Twister inicializado com uma seed.
    uniform_int_distribution<int> random(1, 10); // Distribuição uniforme para números de 1 à 10.
    cout << random(prng) << endl; // Gera um número de 1 à 10 uniformemente via Mersenne Twister.
    cout << random(prng) << endl; // Gera outro número de 1 à 10 uniformemente via Mersenne Twister.
}
```

**<kbd>[resultado online](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b0583c1963d0c4a0)</kbd>**

Comment: `#include <random>` não funciona no **devC++**

Comment: @Rodolfo o melhor que você tem a fazer é parar de usar DevC++. Esse é um IDE muito ultrapassado e não é usado por nenhum ambiente de trabalho. Mesmo assim, como ele usa gcc, verifique se a versão do gcc dele suporta a flag -std=c++11, caso sim, é só usa-lá para funcionar, do contrário pare de usar este ambiente e adote outro. Tem alternativas free e grátis muito melhores.

Comment: beleza vou verificar